# nuxtjs-auth module not fetching user or setting cookeis after successful login request

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js, nuxtjs2

Nuxtjs-auth module was working fine when my local instances of the frontend and backend app were both running on localhost (frontend was on port 3000, backend was on port 8000)

I dockerized the containers; now the frontend is available at http://app.test and the backend at http://api.app.test. The frontend can make requests to the backend, but the nuxtjs-auth module is not working properly: after a succesful login request to the backend, the nuxtjs-auth correctly stores the token as a Bearer token, but it does not attempt to fetch the user (although `user.autoFetch` is set to true) and its `loggedIn` is set to false.

I tried to manually fetch the user myself, which worked, but `loggedIn` was still set to false and the frontend app keeps requiring login, even though the login was successful.

I guess this behavior could be due to subdomains issues. Anyway, I need nuxtjs-auth to behave as it were when the application was running directly on the host's localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the strategy to `local` strategy (previously, it was `laravelSanctum` strategy from the `laravel/Sanctum` provider). I do not know why the issue happened with one strategy but not with another. Takeaway: the bug was not solved, but I found a workaround.